# How to make entire group change color on hover?

Tags: html, css

If you go to http://cascade2.hostei.com/collection.html

And hover over the picture of the chandelier, you will notice the entire group turns from a grey to a blue.
But if you hover over the caption below it, you will notice only the caption turns blue.

How can I change it so when I hover over the caption, it will also turn the border of the picture blue?
Preferably in HTML or CSS.

Ignore the shadow and all of the other errors.
HTML:

```
<center>
<figure class=cheese>
<a class=cheese href="images/cascadelucecatalog.pdf">
   <center><img src="images/cataloguefront.jpg" width="400" height="398"  alt=""/>
</center><figcaption>
<h2><p>2013 Cascade Luce Catalog</p></h2></figcaption></a>
      </figure></center>
```

CSS:

```
.cheese {
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #999999;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #999999;
    color: #FFF;
}
.cheese p{
    color: #FFF;
}
.cheese:hover, .cheese:active, .cheese:focus, .cheese :hover, .cheese :active, .cheese :focus{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #43A6CB;
}
```

Comment: The rules of SO dictate that you show relevant code or a demo. Please do.

Answer (score 4):

You need to target the img when .cheese is hovered.

```
.cheese:hover img {
background-color: #43A6CB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the padding off your image. It's obscuring the background. Apply padding to the parent element if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the background color of the image to white

```
figure img {
padding: 10px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #999999;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #999999;
}
```

Just remove the **background-color: #FFFFFF;** property and everything should work fine.

It looks quite better white a grey border to see where the image ends in my opinion too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, targeting the img on hover

```
.cheese a img:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/tvVg7/1/)